# Error installing levenshtein with pip install

Tags: python, windows, pip, levenshtein-distance

I am trying pip install levenshtein in the command prompt but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: 
/packages/7b/be/21ea38c3d63a1345a338c495ebe7c29c1e5fa915d4a7b71a7b25117a1d10/Levenshtein-0.20.5-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: 
 self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

Anyone who can help?

Comment: What version of Pip and Python are you using? What OS are you using (Windows, I think? What version)? Upgrading Pip may help.

Comment: @9769953 I am using Pip version 3.10 and Python version 3.10 and OS is windows 10 enterprise OS Build 19044.2006

Comment: The error says the server is using a self-signed certificate. `files.pythonhosted.org` is definitely *not* using a self-signed certificate, you can check that from the padlock icon in your browser. Are you using a debugging proxy perhaps? Or working in an environment, eg a cafe with a captive portal, that intercepts SSL connections? Or use a proxy without a proper certificate, eg on a Raspberry ?

Comment: Are you using Fiddler perhaps, or a similar debugging proxy?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no I am not using any of that

Comment: Is it only this package, or have you installed other packages before without problem?

Comment: @9769953 I have installed packages yesterday with no problem.

Comment: It could be a temporary hickup, a (minor) Windows update that caused this, or (if this concerns e.g. a laptop) a new location; or a change in your internet connection (.e.g, at a work place, the wifi could have had an update).

Comment: @9769953 you were right. I was working from home on Friday and this morning at work I managed to do pip install. Thank you

Comment: Funny though how your home setup gave this error. Usually, it's work places where the setup hampers connectivity (as it's often more strict security wise).